# Why Django creates an object of type parent implicitly in multi-table inheritance?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand the multi-table inheritance in django and using the code samples from official [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When executing the following in the python console. it seems that django create a Place object implicitly whenever creating a Restaurant object:

```
>>> Place.objects.all().count()
0

>>> Restaurant.objects.all().count()
0

>>> Restaurant.objects.create(serves_pizza=True)
<Restaurant: Restaurant object (1)>

>>> Place.objects.all().count()
1

>>> Restaurant.objects.all().count()
1

>>> Restaurant.objects.first() is Place.objects.first()
False
```

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Because that's literally what multi table inheritance is.

Comment: Then thank you Daniel Roseman. i had a different thoughts about the multi-table inheritance.